# Windows script the delete a folder, but move files to main

Tags: batch-file, scripting, filesystems

I want to delete a folder but keep the files that are in it

So for example:

I have folded /folder1 and folder1 has folder2 and folder3 and they have files
I want to make it so it deletes the folders and puts all files into one folder.

Comment: What folder do you want to put the files in?

Comment: back into the main folder so lets say root in that example

Comment: So if you have C:\folder1, C:\folder1\folder2, and C:\folder1\folder3 and you delete folder2, its contents go into folder1? And if you delete folder1 its contents and subdirectories go into C:\?

Comment: what OS are you using ?